# C++ socket design

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, client

I am designing a client server socket program using TCP/IP.

The server listens on a certain port, the client program makes 2 connections to the server. One is for command and response and the other is for streaming of data.

For the command and response, I can use the normal blocking socket mode to receive the client command and send the server response.

For the streaming data, the server would wait for the client to send a start stream command and begins continuous sending of data to that client. The issue now is I need the handler to also listen on this connection for the stop stream command. Hence, I was thinking of making this connection non-blocking so that the receive would not block followed by a non-blocking send.

Is this method of implementing the server and client handler efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Boost::asio socket management layer. It's very well written.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime1.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is very efficient.

You can use libraries like [libevent](http://libevent.org/).

Answer (score 0):

From perspective of efficiency, the server should always be designed to use non-blocking sockets, and use event-driven asynchronous I/O architecture. Blocking sockets should be avoided at server side.

Fortunately, there've been a few mature open source frameworks you can use. Among them, libev is most lightweight.